# How can I get JBoss/WildFly to terminate automatically upon application deployment/initialization failure?

Tags: jboss, wildfly, keycloak

I am using WildFly to run the KeyCloak application and want the container to terminate if KeyCloak fails to deploy or initialize. Unfortunately, I do not see a clear way to achieve this and am wondering if anyone knows if this is possible.

When WildFly fails to start, the first error in the logs will usually look like this, followed by a bunch of cascading errors related to StepHanders:

> ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0348: Timeout after [7200] seconds waiting for service container stability. Operation will roll back. Step that first updated the service container was 'add' at address '[("interface" => "management")]'

Is there a way to get WildFly to terminate upon deployment/initialization failure?

Answer (score 0):

You can write your custom script which will grep exception from log files and will shutdown/kill server instance.

Comment: Or take a look at the server status through the jboss-cli or management API and kill it.

Comment: I thought about both of those solutions, but they seem like hacks. I find it hard to believe that an application server lacks such basic native functionality.